# docker-compose + symfony in windows env

Tags: docker, symfony

i've installed docker (windows 10) with wsl2 (ubuntu distro) and added my `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx:1.20.1
        container_name: web
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./nginx.d.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
            - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf            
            - ./www/my-app:/app
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: myphp.dockerFile
        container_name: php
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - web
        volumes:
            - ./www/my-app:/app
    mysql:
        image: mariadb:10.3.28
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - php
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '******'
            MYSQL_USER: 'root'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '******'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: 'my-database'
        command: ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]
        volumes:
            - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
    cache:
        image: redis:5.0.3
        container_name: cache
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 6379:6379
        networks:
            - my-network
        volumes:
            - ./cache:/cache

volumes:
    mysqldata: {}

networks:
    my-network:
        driver: "bridge"
```

So my symfony code is in the `/www/my-app` window's folder. This includes the `/www/my-app/vendor` too.

My application is running extremely slow (50-70 seconds). If i'm correct it's because the `vendor` folder is huge (80MB) and docker creates an image of it every time. Other discussions mentioned that `vendor` folder sould be moved into a new volume, and here i'm stuck with it. How to move and mount that in this case, and how should the docker-compose.yml look like after it?

Comment: I dont think its because of the folder its mostly because u are running it on windows. It was designed for linux , and hence for you to use it on windows it uses windows subsystem for linux which results in a longer time.

Comment: its a know performance bottleneck to use the windows filesystem with docker and wsl backend. I would suggest moving your project into the wsl file system. Apart from that, you probably should mount the vendor folder anyway. You should build an image that you can just deploy. At some point you want to scale and move around servers, using volumes in this fashion is not good in those cases. Even for basic distribution of your application, its counterproductive.